# Chrome. Problems with encoding

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Google Chrome updated to 31.0.1650.63 m

And many sites show me partly "AAOOIIE" text.

For example `https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/510?hl=ru-UA` :
[image]

In Mozilla same page looks good.
What should I do?

Comment: Do you mean to say that the web browser mis-detects the encoding of the binary data delivered by the web server?

Comment: Yes, if I click "View Source" it`s pure russian text in HTML.

Comment: As it happens I have just updated to 31.0.1650.63 m and the page views OK for me. (It viewed OK before the update as well.) The page is encoded as UTF-8 (stated in the Content-Type header) so it's unusual for the browser to get this wrong, or not be capable of displaying this. What encoding is reported if you select Menu > Tools > Encoding. Is it set to "Auto Detect"?

Comment: Yes, "Auto Detect" is checked. Dot is at UTF-8.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, still not. Maybe re-install will help.

Comment: Even re-install doesn`t helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was problem with non-english characters in `"Helvetica Neue"` font. It's popular on web sites. I just removed it from `Control Panel > Fonts` and now all those sites uses `"Arial"`.